# constraining type variables to concrete types

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, type-variables

I have this monomorphic code:

```
import Data.Array.MArray
import Data.Array.IO (IOUArray)
import Data.Ix (Ix)

push :: IOUArray Int Int -> Int -> [Int] -> IO Int
push stack top [] = return top
push stack top (k:ks) = do
  v <- readArray stack k
  if v >= 0 then push stack top ks
            else do writeArray stack k top
                    push stack k ks
```

A fully polymorphic signature for `push` would be:

```
push :: (MArray a e m, Ix e, Num e)  => a e e -> e -> [e] -> m e
```

But I tried to write these partially polymorphic signatures:

```
push :: MArray a e m => a Int e -> Int -> [Int] -> m Int
push :: MArray a e m => a Int Int -> Int -> [Int] -> m Int
push :: MArray a Int m => a Int Int -> Int -> [Int] -> m Int
push :: (MArray a e m, e ~ Int) => a e e  -> e -> [e] -> m e
```

and I get errors like `can't deduce (e ~ Int)`, `can't deduce (MArray a Int m) ...` and `Non type-variable argument in constraint`, `Illegal equational constraint`

Is there a way to constrain the type variable `e` in the first signature to a concrete type like `Int`?

Answer (score 5):

The third signature works if you enable `FlexibleContexts` (as the error suggests):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Data.Array.MArray
import Data.Array.IO (IOUArray)
import Data.Ix (Ix)

push :: MArray a Int m => a Int Int -> Int -> [Int] -> m Int
-- push :: IOUArray Int Int -> Int -> [Int] -> IO Int
push stack top [] = return top
push stack top (k:ks) = do
  v <- readArray stack k
  if v >= 0 then push stack top ks
            else do writeArray stack k top
                    push stack k ks
```

There's [some discussion of this extension](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/FlexibleContexts) on the Haskell Prime wiki.

The fourth signature works with `TypeFamilies` to allow the `e ~ Int` constraint:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
import Data.Array.MArray
import Data.Array.IO (IOUArray)
import Data.Ix (Ix)

push :: (MArray a e m, e ~ Int) => a e e  -> e -> [e] -> m e
-- push :: IOUArray Int Int -> Int -> [Int] -> IO Int
push stack top [] = return top
push stack top (k:ks) = do
  v <- readArray stack k
  if v >= 0 then push stack top ks
            else do writeArray stack k top
                    push stack k ks
```

In this particular case I think it has exactly the same effect on type checking of calling contexts as the other working signature with `FlexibleContexts`, but in general having a type variable with an equality constraint is not quite the same as having a concrete type.

Answer (score 3):

The first signature

```
push :: MArray a e m => a Int e -> Int -> [Int] -> m Int
```

doesn't work because you are reading an array element `v <- readArray stack k` which has type `e`, but then compare it to 0, which is an `Int` or `Integer` (edit: really any `Num`).

The second signature

```
push :: MArray a e m => a Int Int -> Int -> [Int] -> m Int
```

doesn't work because you say that `a e m` is an instance of `MArray`, but then try to *use* a `a Int Int`. GHC tries to unify the required constraint with the given constraint, so it tries to match `e` with `Int`.

Ganesh's answer resolves the other two signatures.

Comment: `0` is not just `Int` or `Integer`, it can be any `Num a => a`.